# Formatting JavaScript jQuery Date format in Java with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, jquery, date, simpledateformat

I get this from JQuery:

```
"Fri Nov 28 2014 10:19:52 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```

How do I format this String into a `Date` object in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
String date="Fri Nov 28 2014 10:19:52 GMT+0100 (CET)";
Date dateTime= new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)").parse(date);
```

The dig is to use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a `String` into `Date`.
For more on `SimpleDateFormat` visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) link.

Comment: Funnily enough, I was using `EEE MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)` but it gave me back `Fri Jan 03 2014 10:19:52 GMT+0100 (CET)`. Your format string works properly if I use `Locale.US` at the end, because it breaks with my locale (Hungarian). Thanks.